# How to make Cluster in arangodb?

Tags: arangodb

Hello I'm using arangodb version 3.1.11,
my question is that how to make a cluster in arangodb 3.1.11
here I've done some changes in /etc/arangodb/arangod.conf 
whenever i enable cluster mode by adding these two line in configuration file which is given below:

[cluster]

disable-dispatcher-kickstarter = no

disable-dispatcher-frontend = no

after adding these lines my arangodb service is not restarted so what is the solution please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The currently recommendet way to start an arangodb cluster without DC/OS is to use the [ArangoDBStarter](https://github.com/arangodb-helper/ArangoDBStarter), which does automatically take care of all those parameters.

You run ArangoDBStarter on the primary node first. You specify the IP its going to be available at.Then on all other nodes telling the instances on those hosts which IP the primary host has - it will output the slave commands so you just need to cut'n'paste them.

If you try a sample setup on a single machine you can invoke ArangoDBStarter multiple times there (At least 3 times in total).

It should get you up and running without any troubles.

Comment: i'm using Ubuntu 16.04 so how can i establish a cluster on my local machine ?

Comment: how to check the cluster is established or not in web interface? if not then how can i see a cluster in web interface ?

Comment: As of ArangoDBStarter 0.6 it will provide you with this information once the cluster is up and running. In general it seems to become http://127.0.0.1:4002 in many cases. Some more documentation will appear over at https://doc.arangodb.com/devel/Manual/Deployment/ArangoDBStarter.html tomorow.

Comment: also I've one question that i to remove a particular node from cluster and how can i know that this particular node is removed?